# Using pointers to matrices in a scanf function

Tags: c, pointers, memory, matrix, scanf

I was playing around with pointers when inputing a matrix with scanf and for some reason, when I run this code, only the first element of every row gets stored correctly.

```
#include "stdio.h"

void main()
{
    int i, j, n, A[10][10];
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            scanf("%d", A + j + i*10);
}
```

This is what I get after inputing 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9 into a 3x3 matrix and printing it:

1 -858993460 -858993460

2 -858993460 -858993460

3 -858993460 -858993460

According to my understanding of how matrices are stored, this should work. Can anyone point out whats wrong with my code?

Comment: `A + j + i*10` is wrong. Change it to like `(int*)A + j + i*10`

Comment: or `A + j + i*10` --> `*(A + i) + j`

Comment: So I need to cast it as a pointer? Why do I not have to do that when using this principle for one dimensional arrays? It works with just A + i or something.

Comment: `A + j + i*10` -> `&A[0][0]+j+i*10`

Comment: Because
The type when `A` is evaluated as an expression is `int (*)[10]`, not `int*`

Comment: Bad pointer math.  `scanf("%d", A + j + i*10);` --> `scanf("%d", &A[i][j]);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declare `A` as

```
int A[10][10];
```

that is, an array of 10 arrays of 10 `int`s each.  Thus, when `A` decays to a pointer to its first element, the type of that pointer is `int (*)[10]`.  That's a pointer to an array of 10 `int`s, not a pointer to a single `int`.  Among the differences is their interaction with pointer arithmetic.  Because pointer arithmetic is defined in terms of the size of the pointed-to type, whenever `i` is nonzero, the expression `A + j + i*10` produces a pointer (to array of 10 `int`s) outside the bounds of array `A`.

The most type-safe way of doing what you want would be to use array syntax to select array elements:

```
&A[i][j]
```

.  Type-correct alternatives that use pointer arithmetic include

```
&(*(A + i))[j]
```

and

```
*(A + i) + j
```

These latter two both rely on the fact that the expression `A + i` is a pointer to an array of `int`; dereferencing that pointer produces an array, which can be the operand of the `[]` operator (and the address of the result then taken).  Alternatively, the array designated by `*(A + i)` decays to a pointer to its first element (i.e. decays to an `int *`) when it appears as an operand of the `+` operator, and adding `j` to that yields a pointer to the `j`<sup>th</sup> element of array `*(A + i)` (which is the same array designated by `A[i]`).

Comment: Oooohh, makes sense. One thing is still bugging me tho. When you use `*(A + i)` you get an array. BUT when you deference it AND it is an operand of the `+` operator, you get a pointer to its first element. Right?

Comment: Yes, the expression `*(A + i)` designates an array.  Just like any other array, when that array is evaluated as an operand of `+` (or of most other operators) it is automatically converted ("decays") to a pointer to its first element.  There are very few contexts in which an array does not decay to a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Bad pointer math.

```
A + j + i * 10
```

When `A` is used in `A + j + i*10`, it becomes the pointer to its first element, which is an array of 10 `int`.  Every `1` added to `A` offsets its address by 40 bytes.

Recommend to use `&A[i][j]` instead.

Code re-worked to show addresses used.

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main() {
  int i, j, n, A[10][10];
  n = 3;
  char *base = (char*) A;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      char *offset0 = (char*) (&A[i][j]);
      char *offset1 = (char *) (A + j + i * 10);
      printf("%d %d %3td %3td\n", i, j, offset0 - base, offset1 - base);
    }
}
```

Output

```
0 0   0   0
0 1   4  40
0 2   8  80
1 0  40 400
1 1  44 440
1 2  48 480
2 0  80 800
2 1  84 840
2 2  88 880
```